# golang webservers accept cookies despite them being expired

Tags: go, cookies, gorilla, mux

So I was writing a backend using Go, and while I was testing the login/logout function I noticed that if I try to access a page with an expired cookie I'm allowed to do so. This happens only if I use a faulty client, because if I use my browser it works correctly, which I guess means that the cookie is deleted from the web-browser but not from my back-end.

I've tested different solutions, but nothing seems to work, what I've noticed is this: I've taken note of the pointer of the map which maps the cookies and I've noticed that despite setting "authenticated" value to false when the faulty client tries to access the page the map has its value set to true.

this is the middle ware that handles pages in which the user should be logged in and this should block the faulty client from logging in because "authenticated" value from session-handler should be false ( but it is true, despite being set to false before )

```
func (s *server) loggedInOnly(handlerFunc http.HandlerFunc) http.HandlerFunc {

    return func(writer http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request) {
        session, _ := s.store.Get(request, "session-handler")
        log.Printf("loggedInOnly: %p %v", &session.Values, session.Values)
        if auth, ok := session.Values["authenticated"].(bool); !ok || !auth {
            http.Error(writer, "Forbidden", http.StatusForbidden)
            return
        }
        handlerFunc(writer, request)
    }

}
```

this is the logout function which should delete the cookie ( but it doesn't delete it internally )

```
func (s *server) handleLogout() http.HandlerFunc {

    return func(writer http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request) {
        session, _ := s.store.Get(request, "session-handler")
        session.Values["authenticated"] = false
        session.Options.MaxAge = -1
        session.Save(request, writer)
        log.Printf("logout: %p, %v", &session.Values, session.Values)
        fmt.Fprint(writer, "Succesfully logged out")
        log.Printf("%v was logged out", writer)
    }

}
```

and this is the login function

```
func (s *server) handleLogin() http.HandlerFunc {

    return func(writer http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request) {
        log.Printf("handle login called")
        session, _ := s.store.Get(request, "session-handler")

        // can login or not

        session.Values["authenticated"] = true
        session.Save(request, writer)

        Success(writer, "successfully logged in")
    }

}
```

I should expect the cookie to be invalid from my webserver so that when the faulty client tries to reconnect authenticated is set to false and he shouldn't be able to access loggedInOnly pages, instead I he can because authenticated value is set to true ( despite being set to false right before ).

these are the logs:

```
2019/01/05 17:00:00 loggedInOnly: 0xc0421960b0 map[authenticated:true]
2019/01/05 17:00:00 logout: 0xc0421960b0, map[authenticated:false]
2019/01/05 17:00:01 loggedInOnly: 0xc0420a4560 map[authenticated:true]
2019/01/05 17:00:01 logout: 0xc0420a4560, map[authenticated:false]
```

as you can see "authenticated" is set before to false then immediatly after it is true despite nothing happening in between

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're expecting. Why do you believe the cookie is expired? And where do you expect your code to reject expired cookies?  I don't actually see cookies being used at all in your code.

Comment: ` if auth, ok := session.Values["authenticated"].(bool); !ok || !auth ` (in loggedInOnly func)
this should be false after handleLogout is called, but if a faulty client access the page using an expired session cookie it can still access it, the session cookie is create in handleLogin func.

Comment: You haven't answered my questions. 1. Why do you believe the cookie is expired?  2. Where does your code check for expired cookies?

Comment: I thought         `session.Options.MaxAge = -1` does make the cookie expire

Comment: Setting a cookie's max age to -1 tells the client to expire it immediately, yes. But, as you've said, that's irrelevant, since your "faulty client" isn't expiring the cookie. Which means the cookie still has _some other_ MaxAge value... why do you think _that cookie_ is expired?  And where is your code checking for expired cookies?

Comment: Simply trusting a client to do what it's told is not secure--and you seem to be expecting your server to do some security checks. __Where are these checks?__

Comment: That's my point, I thought it was handled internally gorilla's session, I didnt do those checks because I didn't know they had to be done.

Comment: @ThunderCat, one of gorilla's default session storage [uses browser cookies](https://godoc.org/github.com/gorilla/sessions#CookieStore), which presumably the OP uses. mrclx, you cannot rely on that cookie. Even if you change it's contents by modifying the session, clients can still replay old versions of the cookie. Even honest clients can do that, because they never saw the response with the updated value (because the train just entered a tunnel).

Comment: Ok, so how do I remove that cookie from the CookieStore? This is what I'd like to know... Or how to make it impossible to replay the Cookie? Because if I restart the server if  I try to replay the cookie I cannot ( because I guess it is not inside the cookieStore), but once the cookie is set it can be replayed despite setting MaxAge to zero. From google I cannot seem to find any solution. I just want to make that cookie unusable or remove it. I can perhaps save it in a slice and range over this slice to look for invalid each time loggedInOnly is called. But I guess removing it would be better.